# IIS paths ignoring application folder

Tags: iis

I lack the know-how with IIS and IIS manager to even have the proper google terms here, so I hope you'll keep that in mind if you're tempted to click that downvote button.

Thanks.

Okay, so I have an angular application that I just moved over to an an IIS server after developing it locally, without using IIS.

The IIS-based copy of the application works, in that it will serve `index.html` as expected. Unfortunately, links to external files (.ccs, .js, etc) are all broken.

The application lives in this folder:

```
\\iis.dev.local\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\the-application
```

And it's .css file lives here:

```
\\iis.dev.local\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\the-application\css\main.css
```

As originally written, the link to that `.css` file, which we'll call "link 1":

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

Which worked fine in development, but doesn't work on IIS.

However, this *does* work, which we'll call "link 2":

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/the-application/css/main.css">
```

See how I had to add the folder that the application itself sits in? Which is strange, because relative to `index.html`, "link 1" should be correct--but it isn't.

How can I convince my application that its base url should be the folder it's sitting in, and not one level above?

Random partial guesses and/or useful information?

1) The application sits in the default application pool.

2) Something, something `web.config`?

EDIT: screwed up some paths.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `<base>` HTML Element to set the root.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_base_tag.htm

In your example it would be:

```
<base href="https://www.the-application.com" />
```

Then the rest should flow, with relative paths.

Comment: Seems not. I tried `<base href="http://dev-iis-1.dev.local/">`, `<base href="http://dev-iis-1.dev.local/the-application">` and a few variations along those lines, but the links remain broken.

Answer (score 0):

When developing on your local machine you are most likely running under a Virtual Folder under the DEFAULT website.

When you move to a server you are now running at the ROOT of the site.

**Options:**

1. Create a new site on your DEV Machine at the Root of IIS. Then use this path to test your site. When you migrate to production the paths will be the same.
2. Create a variable with the correct path, and if running LOCALHOST (in the url) use one path, else the other. Use JavaScript to add the link to your HTML (Something I have done with a JavaScript site under IIS for Cordova Development).
3. Change your page extension from .html to .aspx *(yeah I know who wants to do that...)* then change your links as follows. *(I had to remove the starting < and ending /> in the code below, it would not format in the post)*

link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/main.css") %>"

When you browse your source afterward you will see... (or when you navigate to sub-pages it will put the correct relative path in place for you)

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
```